# Does a donation site need login?

Tags: website-design, login

I have a task to redesign a donation website. The top navigation bar has search for donation events and login/register.

Is there a need for a **login/register** option? Especially considering when someone wants to donate, they can do it anonymously.

Answer (score 8):

You should definitely offer the option to login, just like online shopping sites offer their visitors the option to buy as a guest, buy as a registered user.

This could be a nice feature for registered users, displaying your users what they donated so far, when they donated and to whom they donated in the past...

But take care, don't break the donation process, don't ask in the beginning, ask at the end when the user basically is done with the donation.

Comment: Something I often see is the option to sign up/login or continue without an account at the beginning of the process. I tend to prefer that myself but it's quite subjective.

Comment: Thank you. i have more one question, which information is more important to highlight on the navbar. "look for donation events" or "login/register"?

Comment: @NandaFebrianA if donations are the main point of the site, then searching for a cause is more important than register. Always focus on the goals of the site user when designing.

Answer (score 2):

My thoughts are to ditch the wording login/register as that could be a blocker to donations. Just simply say “donate” in the header, then go through the flow of making a donation asking for card details and basic information like email, name etc.

Once the donation is complete then say would you like to create an account and list out the advantages of having an account to the user.

The main goal is to get donations, creating an account is a secondary goal so it’s important that the login/register doesn’t distract the user away

Answer (score 0):

Recently I am working on a similar project to this. after testing donation process UX, I decided to give up login/register process for simple donation. Login/register process make sense for track previous donations and these kind of stuffs.
**Don't make user create account and login for voluntary works like donation,... .**

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the basis is the cash flow process - you need to ensure proper security and facilitate the process.

Both the concept with an account and without an account is to some extent justified

**Yes**

- gives greater possibilities in the scope of data collection, users, which at a later stage opens up many paths (gamification, rankings etc.)
- in theory, it can increase brand attachment and loyalty.

**No**

- a faster process can increase the rate of people who donate (hypothesis)
- it is easier to make a one-time action, without creating an account or providing sensitive data
- sometimes people don't want to set up an account

In addition, you can give both the option with an account and without an account - however, this involves more expensive implementation.